# What is "main" in package.json for a language extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

So I've been working on a Language Support extension for VS Code (repo found [here](https://github.com/u2berggeist/ANSYS_CFX_VSCode_Ext)) for a few days now. I've run into a ton of bugs (the documentation really isn't that great for someone who literally just wants certain words highlighted...). The main one right now that I have a ton of questions about and can't find anything about is the `main` entry of the `package.json` file.

So on with the questions:

1. I know from [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-hello-world#_the-extension-manifest-packagejson) that `main` specifies a directory to a file.
   What does that file do?
2. I've looked through several different extension's to try and figure
   out what it does, but I noticed that the directory paths all start
   with `"./out/......"`, even though there is no directory called
   `out`. [VS code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-hello-world#_the-structure-of-an-extension) even has a directory labeled `out`. So, what is `out`?
3. I used the Yeoman extension generator and it didn't include a `main` file or an `out` directory. Should the extension have those? Did I mess something up?

If you have any questions let me know. Thanks!

Edit: I forgot to add a question:

The main reason I care about `main` is that I'm trying to use the `activationEvents` field and VS Code says that both the `activationEvent` and the `main` must be specified. In this case, what does `main` need to actually do?

Comment: The main file is the first file to be executed in a project. So that if you execute `node .` that file will be ran.
The `out` directory is the directory for the output of the compilation process. When you built your project, you will find the produced package in the specified folder. If you don't include a main or an out nothing happens, not all the projects require it.

Comment: Thanks @CristianTraìna! I forgot to add an important detail to the problem description that explains why I'm trying to figure out the `main`. tl;dr, VS Code is asking for a `main` if I want to use the `activationEvents` field in the manifest file. Any idea why? Or whether or not I should event be interested in the `activationEvents`? 
I mainly just want the syntax highlighting to occur when I open the right file types (there are a few).

Answer (score 1):

`main` doesn't specify a directory, but the file which contains your extension code (at least the main code like the `activate` function). Somewhere you have to implement the things you can activate via `activationEvents`, right? Maybe you can even specify a folder provided you have an index.js file there or a local package.json file which is used to resolve file names. I haven't tried that myself. It's easier to use a file name.

You have to keep in mind here to specify the code file as seen from the installed extension. When you have a TS project your code will be transpiled to JS before the extension is executed. It's not mandatory, but the defacto standard for these transpiled files is the `out` folder (right beside your package.json file). This folder mirrors the source folder, but contains the transpiled JS and the maps files.

The output folder is specified either on the command line (e.g. when you run tsc manually) or in the tsconfig.json file (see `compilerOptions` -> `outDir`).

Side note: the leading `./` is not really required for the out folder but triggers special handling in other situations (like when resolving imports), where a leading `./` avoids module resolution via `node_modules`. So, people tend to use `./out` instead of `out` for consistency.

About the yeoman generated files: I haven't used it for a while and thought it would also generate your extension.ts file (and enter that as the main file in package.json). If that doesn't happen you might have hit a bug or did something wrong. In any case, creating that file and adding it to the `main` entry is a matter of seconds.

Comment: Thanks for all the information!! I follow most of it, but I'm a bit stuck as to what to do next. You mentioned that I could just quickly create an `extension.ts` file since Yeoman didn't put one in my directory. Do I need to have anything in the `extension.ts`? And does it need to go anywhere specific in the file path?

Comment: Also, general FYI to anyone who looks here in the future, I've submitted a issue to the Yo Code Generator GitHub. It can be seen [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-generator-code/issues/99)

Comment: According to [this description](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/yocode#_new-extension-typescript) and what's in the .md file there should be an extension.ts file (or extension.js for a JS project): `Templates out a package.json file and an extension main file.`